# How to insert values into temp table while executing query

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using laravel framework for developing APIS , i have a challenging situation while executing my current query at that time i have to create temporary table with some columns and i have to insert some data based on current running query column values,can anyone please give me some idea how to acheive this one?

```
$q = user::query();
//some joins and where conditions stuff is there here
$q->addselect(“col1 as UserName”)
if($data[“name”]==“test”){

DB::statement('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp SELECT ...i want to insert UserName value here in my temp table column called tempCol');

}
$q->paginate();
```